# Rowsum with Dynamic Column Range

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I am working with a large health insurance dataset and I am interested in participants with certain claims codes. One of my inclusion criteria is that the participant has to have be insured for one year before and one year after the claim date. E.g., if they were injured 9/27/2017, they need insurance from 9/27/2016-9/27/2018.

I have tried doing a simple rowsum, and using apply, but both have the same issue: `in from:to : numerical expression has # elements: only the first used`. Right now, I have the range saved as variables in the dataframe. It think I understand why I am having the issue--it is expecting a number and receiving a vector. How can I get it to conditionally select columns to sum. I will include my code below.

In my example, I am just trying to count the number of months a participant is insured for 6 month before and after their accident. The `ins_#_#` variables are a simple YES/NO for whether or not participants were insured that month. Any guidance is appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id= seq(1,100),
                 injury_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2017/01/01'), as.Date('2017/12/31'), by="day"), 100),
                 ins_07_16 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_08_16 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_09_16 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_10_16 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_11_16 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_12_16 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_01_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_02_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_03_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_04_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_05_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_06_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_07_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_08_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_09_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_10_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_11_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_12_17 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_01_18 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_02_18 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_03_18 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_04_18 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_05_18 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE),
                 ins_06_18 = sample(c(0,1), replace = TRUE))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(month = as.numeric(format(as.Date(injury_date), "%m")), #pulling month of injury
         low_mo = month + 2,
         high_mo = month + 14)


df$insured <- rowSums(df[df$low_mo:df$high_mo]) #only uses first element

df$insured <- apply(df[df$low_mo:df$high_mo], 1, sum) #only uses first element
```

---

Edit: 
Although I did not specify that I wanted a fast solution, I am working with a lot of data so I tested which of @akrun's solutions was the fastest. I changed the dataframe so it was 1e5 (100,000) rows. The results are below in case anyone is curious.

```
microbenchmark(o1 <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) sum(df[i, df$low_mo[i]:df$high_mo[i]])),
               o2 <- {colInd <- Map(`:`, df$low_mo, df$high_mo);
               rowInd <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(colInd));
               as.vector(tapply(df[-(1:2)][cbind(rowInd, unlist(colInd)-2)], 
                                rowInd, FUN = sum))},
               o3 <- {colInd1 <- Map(function(x, y) which(!seq_along(df) %in% x:y), df$low_mo, df$high_mo);
               rowInd1 <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(colInd1));
               rowSums(replace(df, cbind(rowInd1, unlist(colInd1)), NA)[-(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)},
               times = 5)


     Unit: milliseconds



   expr         min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval
     o1  20408.5072 20757.0285 20903.9386 20986.2275 21069.3163 21298.6137     5
     o2    433.5463   436.3066   448.6448   455.6551   456.8836   460.8325     5
     o3    470.6834   482.4449   492.9594   485.6210   504.1353   521.9122     5

> identical(o1, o2)
[1] TRUE
> identical(o2, o3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Or could be `sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) sum(df[i, df$low_mo[i]:df$high_mo[i]]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of way to do this.  Loop through the sequence of rows, subset the dataset by the row index, and the columns generated by taking the sequence of 'low_mo' and 'high_mo' for each row, get the `sum`

```
o1 <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), function(i) sum(df[i, df$low_mo[i]:df$high_mo[i]]))
```

---

Or another option is to extract the elements based on the `row/column` index and then do a group by `sum`

```
colInd <- Map(`:`, df$low_mo, df$high_mo)
rowInd <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(colInd))
o2 <- as.vector(tapply(df[-(1:2)][cbind(rowInd, unlist(colInd)-2)], 
        rowInd, FUN = sum))
identical(o1, o2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another approach is to change the column values that are not in the sequence to `NA` and use the `rowSums`

```
colInd1 <- Map(function(x, y) which(!seq_along(df) %in% x:y), df$low_mo, df$high_mo)
rowInd1 <- rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(colInd1))
o3 <- rowSums(replace(df, cbind(rowInd1, unlist(colInd1)), 
               NA)[-(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)
identical(o1, o3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun--your answers were helpful and informative. I really appreciate it! I had not use sapply or tapply before, but it's time for me to learn more about the apply family. Thanks again!